# using image as form label works in safari but not firefox or chrome

Tags: forms, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I have a form built with bootstrap with 8 radio buttons.  I want to use images as the labels so that when soeone clicks on the image, the radio button is selected.  My code works in safari but not firefox or chrome.  What is wrong?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pictures" class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="picture_form" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="9O16lD41yDMPhIBnqE73EQpJAeXoefz9Ifwd67IUD94=" /></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <label for="picture_shape_yellow_mask">
                <img alt="Yellowshape" class="img-responsive" src="/assets/shapes/yellowshape.svg" />
            </label>
            <input id="picture_shape_yellow_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="yellow_mask" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div >
            <label for="picture_shape_pink_mask">
                <img alt="Pinkshape" class="img-responsive" src="/assets/shapes/pinkshape.svg" />
            </label>
            <input id="picture_shape_pink_mask" name="picture[shape]" type="radio" value="pink_mask" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: try setting `label` as `display:inline-block`

Comment: I tried it but it did not work

Comment: have you added any other styles can you create a fiddle or snippet

Comment: There are no other styles.  Here's the fiddle, but i cant figure out how to upload images to it so it's pretty useless: http://jsfiddle.net/philip7899/n7y9s617/

Comment: I just got the picture in the fiddle.  For some reason, my exact code works in the fiddle in firefox but not on my localhost or production environment.

Comment: try setting as `background-image` and see